# UIScrollView is eating up my swipe gestures Swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have the below code that sets up a vertical scrollview My question is that the views within the view controllers do not respond accurately to swipe gestures. For example in this scrollview, bottomVc contains swipe gestures for left and right swipes. When this view controller is isolated in another project it works flawlessly, but the swipe gestures don't work when it is within the scrollview below. I was wondering how I could fix this issue so that my viewconttollers can handle swipe gestures while being in the scrollview. Also FYI, the code that controls the other view controllers are in separate files along with the swipe gestures. 
The code:
    import UIKit

```
class VerticalScrollViewController: UIViewController, SnapContainerViewControllerDelegate {

var topVc: UIViewController!
var middleVc: UIViewController!
var bottomVc: UIViewController!
var scrollView: UIScrollView!

class func verticalScrollVcWith(middleVc: UIViewController,
                                topVc: UIViewController?=nil,
                                bottomVc: UIViewController?=nil) -> VerticalScrollViewController {
    let middleScrollVc = VerticalScrollViewController()

    middleScrollVc.topVc = topVc
    middleScrollVc.middleVc = middleVc
    middleScrollVc.bottomVc = bottomVc

    return middleScrollVc
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view:
    setupScrollView()
}

func setupScrollView() {
    scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.bounces = false



    let view = (
        x: self.view.bounds.origin.x,
        y: self.view.bounds.origin.y,
        width: self.view.bounds.width,
        height: self.view.bounds.height
    )

    scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: view.x, y: view.y, width: view.width, height: view.height)
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

    let scrollWidth: CGFloat  = view.width
    var scrollHeight: CGFloat

    if topVc != nil && bottomVc != nil {
        scrollHeight  = 3 * view.height
        middleVc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.width, height: view.height)
        topVc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.height, width: view.width, height: view.height)
        bottomVc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 2 * view.height, width: view.width, height: view.height)

        addChildViewController(topVc)
        addChildViewController(middleVc)
        addChildViewController(bottomVc)

        scrollView.addSubview(topVc.view)
        scrollView.addSubview(middleVc.view)
        scrollView.addSubview(bottomVc.view)

        topVc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        middleVc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        bottomVc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        //scrollView.contentOffset.y = middleVc.view.frame.origin.y
        scrollView.contentOffset.y = topVc.view.frame.origin.y

    } else if topVc == nil {
        scrollHeight  = 2 * view.height
        middleVc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.width, height: view.height)
        bottomVc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.height, width: view.width, height: view.height)

        addChildViewController(middleVc)
        addChildViewController(bottomVc)

        scrollView.addSubview(middleVc.view)
        scrollView.addSubview(bottomVc.view)

        middleVc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        bottomVc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0

    } else if bottomVc == nil {
        scrollHeight  = 2 * view.height
        topVc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.width, height: view.height)
        middleVc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.height, width: view.width, height: view.height)

        addChildViewController(topVc)
        addChildViewController(middleVc)

        scrollView.addSubview(topVc.view)
        scrollView.addSubview(middleVc.view)

        topVc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        middleVc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        scrollView.contentOffset.y = middleVc.view.frame.origin.y

    } else {
        scrollHeight  = view.height
        middleVc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.width, height: view.height)

        addChildViewController(middleVc)
        scrollView.addSubview(middleVc.view)
        middleVc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollWidth, height: scrollHeight)
    scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false

}


func outerScrollViewShouldScroll() -> Bool {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < middleVc.view.frame.origin.y || scrollView.contentOffset.y > middleVc.view.frame.origin.y {

        return false

    } else {

        return true
    }

}

}
```

Comment: The `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` should have the methods you need. specifically: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624208-gesturerecognizer

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol to your class, then adding this method to return `true` :

```
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

Should work, unless your controller setup is somehow preventing proper touch recognition..

Comment:  You beat me to it!

Comment: In the scrollview class or the individual view controller classes?

Comment: In the class that contains the scrollviews, and ideally in any subviews that contain touch intensive (dragging or long press) or scrollable elements themselves (collections, tables, etc.)

Comment: Do you have to assign the delegate manually when you are adding the tap gesture? And does this work if the scrollview is consuming tableview swipe to delete gestures?